# Why does ensureCapacity not throw OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

I was reading through java docs and came across this function:`ensureCapacity(int minCapacity)`

What I wonder is that it does not throw `OutOfMemoryError`. Can anyone suggest why as it seems obvious that anyone to put numbers larger then memory of machine.

Link: relevant [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29)

P.S.: Please bear if I am being naive.

Comment: OutOfMemoryError is not generally listed as a possible exception from individual instructions.  This is true for most if not all subclasses of Error, since they are pervasive and not generally considered to be handleable.

Comment: Just about _anything_ can throw an `OutOfMemoryError`, but that doesn't mean you should try to catch it or deal with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why is it not mentioned in the documentation?**

Please note that the entire [`Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) class of `Throwable` does not have to be explicitely mentioned in the documentation. The same goes for `RuntimeException`. Only checked `Exceptions` have to be present in the documentation, like `IOException`.

The general idea behind `Error` classes, as I understand them, is that they represent situations that can happen virtually at any point and are very difficult to recover from. Mentioning these in all possible classes and methods would be pointless.

**Proof that it is thrown**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class OOMETest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> ();
        listOfLists.ensureCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        while (true) {
            ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
            list.ensureCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            listOfLists.add(list);
        }
    }
}
```

And the stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2760)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2734)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacity(ArrayList.java:167)
    at OOMETest.main(OOMETest.java:9)
```

**Should `Errors` be caught?**

I digress here because of another answer to this question I read. Somebody stated that "you shouldn't try to catch or handle it".

While recovering from such situation indeed is virtually impossible, an `Error` may be worth catching just to generate an appropriate debug entry or attempt to close files, streams, connections, save unsaved resources, etc.

Comment: I guess OP meant to ask why is it not mentioned in the signature, e.g. "public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) throws OutOfMemoryError"

Answer (score 2):

Only the exceptions/errors that you want the calling code to handle should be specified in the throws clause. You wouldn't expect caller to handle running out of memory, so it is not mentioned. That's a runtime condition you shouldn't be trying to recover from.

Answer (score 0):

It does throw `OutOfMemoryError`. The java doc does only say that `ensureCapacity`

> Increases the capacity of this ArrayList instance, if necessary.

While it does this it may throw `OutOfMemoryError`.

try running this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int i=0;
while(true) {
    l.add(i++);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OutOfMemoryError` is not mentioned in the javadoc as it's not a CheckedException and as such it's not part of the API-specification.

It's not even an `Exception` but an `Error`, so you shouldn't try to catch or handle it since there might have already been some damage done to your runtime-environment...

Comment: The "you shouldn't try to catch or handle it" part is an opinion, and one that I disagree with. While recovering from such situation is virtually impossible, an `Error` may be worth catching just to generate an appropriate debug entry or close files, streams, connections.

Comment: @Dariusz I agree about the catching, but mor in a kind of general, aplication-wide Error-handling than after some specific call, since - as we seem to agree - you won't be able to do much about it.